# Asp.net in mono in Linux: ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, mono

I created an ASP.Net project in Visual Studio 15 on Windows and copied it to my Raspberry Pi 2 which I run 'Jessie' on. I installed mono-complete and now tried to start the ASP.Net project, but in the file "BundleConfig.cs" it doesn't find ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping in System.Web.UI. It should be in there but it can't find it for whatever reason

Does anyone have an idea what I should add?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a project in mono on linux and then copied this to Visual Studio and it worked.